# Wanted but not invoked: Mockito sharedPreferences when multiple tests are there

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-sharedpreferences

I have written 2 test cases which will test 2 functions of a class which does similar kind of functiomality.

This is my PrefHelper class in project:

```
public String getID() {
    if(ID==null) {
        ID = sharedpreferences.getString(_ID, null);
    }
    return ID ;
}

public void setID(String ID ) {
    prefsEditor.putString(_ID,ID );
    prefsEditor.apply();
    this.ID = ID ;
}

public String getApiBasePath() {
    if(apiBasePath==null) {
        apiBasePath = sharedpreferences.getString(API_BASE_PATH, null);
    }
    return apiBasePath;
}

public void setApiBasePath(String apiBasePath) {
    prefsEditor.putString(API_BASE_PATH,apiBasePath);
    prefsEditor.apply();
    this.apiBasePath = apiBasePath;
}
```

And following is my test class:

```
@Mock
Context context;

@Mock
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Mock
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private  PrefsHelper prefsHelper;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(context.getSharedPreferences(anyString(),anyInt())).thenReturn(sharedPreferences);
    when(sharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(editor);
    when(sharedPreferences.getString(anyString(),isNull(String.class))).thenReturn(null);
    when(editor.putString(anyString(),anyString())).thenReturn(editor);
    prefsHelper =  PrefsHelper.getInstance(context);

}


@Test
public void apiBasePathTest(){

    String returnNull=prefsHelper.getApiBasePath();
    verify(sharedPreferences,times(1)).getString(anyString(),isNull(String.class));
    assertEquals(null,returnNull);


    doNothing().when(editor).apply();
    final ArgumentCaptor<String> stringsCaptor =
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    prefsHelper.setApiBasePath("basePath");
    verify(editor,times(1)).putString(anyString(),stringsCaptor.capture());
    verify(editor,times(1)).apply();
    assertEquals("basePath", stringsCaptor.getAllValues().get(0));

    String returnNonNull=prefsHelper.getApiBasePath();
    verify(sharedPreferences,times(1)).getString(anyString(),isNull(String.class));
    assertEquals("basePath",returnNonNull);


}


@Test
public void IDTest(){
    String returnNull=prefsHelper.getID();
    assertEquals(null,returnNull);
    verify(sharedPreferences,times(1)).getString(anyString(),isNull(String.class));

    doNothing().when(editor).apply();
    final ArgumentCaptor<String> stringsCaptor =
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    prefsHelper.setID("ID");
    verify(editor,times(1)).putString(anyString(),stringsCaptor.capture());
    verify(editor,times(1)).apply();
    assertEquals("ID", stringsCaptor.getAllValues().get(0));

    String returnNonNull=prefsHelper.getID();
    verify(sharedPreferences,times(1)).getString(anyString(),isNull(String.class));
    assertEquals("ID",returnNonNull);

}
```

First test case runs fine, it fails in second test at all the verify method. Its assert true works fine but verify fails in all cases and I get the below error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
sharedPreferences.getString(<any>, isNull());
-> at PrefsHelperTest.IDTest
```

Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. I am surprised that it works fine on first test but fails on second, where both test are doing similar functionality.

Comment: peoblem has been sloved. i had declared the class as singleton hence i was facing problem during testing.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem! Please answer your own question in the space below, and (in two days) mark it as accepted. This will help show that your problem was resolved; others with the same question in the future may upvote it too!